# render a 3d car model in vulkan, but texture flickers while rotating

Tags: 3d, vulkan

I have a problem when I try to render a car.

[texture flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHBAw.png)

As the image shows that some fragments have wrong textures. These small triangles keep flickering during rotating. I suspect it may result from z-fighting, but I failed to fix it.

Following are some code snippets.

```
VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterInfo{
  .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
  .pNext = nullptr,
  .depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE,
  .rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE,
  .polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL,
  .cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_NONE,
  .frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE,
  .depthBiasEnable = VK_TRUE,
  .depthBiasConstantFactor = 1.0f,
  .depthBiasClamp = 0.0f,
  .depthBiasSlopeFactor = 1.0f,
  .lineWidth = 1};
```

Comment: It's near impossible to help with such little information. Please post or link to the relevant source parts, esp. how you setup your perspective matrix.

Comment: Thx for your help, and I have add some more information.